# use asp .net identity user in another project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I've 2 projects that one of them is asp web api and another is class library for example data access layer, also I've two entity framework context in each other.
I'm using ApiUser of web api in web api project.

This is my ApiUser in webApi project:

```
public class ApiUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int? OrganizationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; internal set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApiUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

This is my dbContext in web api project:

```
public class ApiDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApiUser>
{
    public ApiDbContext()
        : base("PelicanConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApiDbContext Create()

    {
        return new ApiDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApiUser>().ToTable("ApiUsers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ApiRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("ApiUserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("ApiUserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("ApiUserLogins");


    }
}
```

This is my context in data access project:

```
 public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext() : base("AppConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    }

    public DbSet<ApiUser> ApiUsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Reception> Receptions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Box> Boxes { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Ignore<ApiUser>();
    }
}
```

For using ApiUser in both project I had to Ignore ApiUser in data access project context.
How can I access ApiUser DbSet in data access context?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `namespace` in front of the class object so the compiler would know which one to use, no need to ignore. You can try and cast the two objects from/to each other.

You should look at how `Dependancy Injection` works for solving this issue, for example you could create an `Interface` to describe the ApiUser, IApiUser and let the two different ApiUser classes inherit from this interface.

https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/implementation-of-dependency-injection-pattern-in-csharp